# Renting a car without driver's license in Spain

Tags: europe, driving, car-rentals, spain, driving-licenses

my wife and I are going on holiday to Menorca soon and we were thinking of renting a car. The problem is, she can drive and has a valid drivers license from non-EU country but doesn't have a credit card. I, on the other hand, have a credit card to my name but cannot drive. Most rental car companies that I'm finding online require that the credit card is on the name of the main driver. As you can see this is a big problem for us as I can't rent because I don't have a driver's license and she can't do it because she doesn't have a credit card.
Is there any way around this? We've travelled to Brazil for 3 months in the past and we're able to rent a car for the duration using my credit card and her driver's license so we were surprised when we found we couldn't do it in Europe.

Comment: Can you ask your credit card issuer to issue another card on your account in your wife's name?  Many card issuers in the US, at least, will do that.

Comment: Thanks, I've just applied to add her to my card. I didn't realise you could do that.

Comment: @phoog You should put that as an answer, because it's a good solution.

Comment: I have successfully done this in Germany travelling with a colleague.  The booking (and deposit) were in his name on a corporate card, but his licence had been temporarily revoked and I was driving.  However I had a credit card withme that I could have used if necessary, otherwise I would have been worried about it

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there any way around this?

Many card issuers will issue a second card on your account in your wife's name.  This should satisfy the rental agency.